# The CancelableOperation run completely when I click on cancel

Tags: flutter, future

I run this code in order to cancel the method **_trytest()** when the user changes his mind.

Declare the value **cancellableOperation** of the library async: ^2.9.0:

```
  CancelableOperation<void> cancellableOperation =
      CancelableOperation.fromFuture(
    Future.value('future result'),
    onCancel: () {},
  );
```

Part of the code :

```
 _isloading
                  ? Column(
                      children: [
                        Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          child: Text('Cancel'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            cancellableOperation.cancel();
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  : ElevatedButton(
                      child: Text('Delete Account'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _isloading = true;
                        });

                        cancellableOperation = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(
                            _trytest(),
                            onCancel: () => {
                                  debugPrint('onCancel'),
                                  
                                  cancellableOperation.cancel(),
                                  setState(() {
                                    _isloading = false;
                                  })
                                });
                      },
                    ),
```

the code of _trytest() :

```
  Future<void> _trytest() async {
    print('on _trytest');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4)).then((value) => {
          print("Completed"),
          setState(() {
            _isloading = false;
          })
        });
  }
```

when I click on cancel **_trytest()** run completely even if CancelableOperation enter on mode cancel!

On the console :

> flutter: on _trytest

> flutter: onCancel

> flutter: Completed

Comment: Could you include the error on the console?

Comment: Can you include more code showing the lifecycle of the widget? What steps does the app take to get to this error screen? Also include the code of `makingSurePopUp`.

Comment: @VictorEronmosele, I made the code more simple in order to make the problem more clear.

Comment: are you sure you pressed the cancel button before 4 seconds?

Comment: @OMiShah, yes,I'm sure